# How to put two arrows in different directions with text over and under them

Tags: arrows

I found here in stackexchange some latex code to make two arrows in the same direction with text over and under it, by using the package extpfeil.

`\newextarrow{\xrightrightarrows}{{20}{20}{20}{20}}{\bigRelbar\bigRelbar{\bigtwoarrowsleft\rightarrow\rightarrow}}`

Now I want the bottom arrow to point left, and I don't know how to change this. I tried with this:

`\newextarrow{\xleftrightarrows}{{20}{20}{20}{20}}{\bigRelbar\bigRelbar{\bigtwoarrowsleft\rightarrow\leftarrow}}`

But it doesn't work, since all it does is this.[image]

Comment: Wait, why is the documentation in German!? No English version...

Comment: Okay, looks like exact duplicate. (just spam spaces in `\xfromto` until it's long enough)